# Bald spots with Hair Particles

Tags: particles, hair

I’m trying to add fur on top of a hand that belongs to a character of mine but for some reason independent of what I do, there are always bald spots. Increasing parent count or children doesn’t do anything. I tried changing from “random” to “jittered” and turning off “even distrribution” but nothing works. These strange areas are even viewable from viewport. I’m using it in 2.8 but I tried it in 2.79 to no help.

Viewport shows the areas in a dark tone:

[image]

Render:

[image]

The fur in general looks kinda mushy or paste like in certain areas as well. Is that related?

Blend. file:

[image]

EDIT: The question that they offered did not solve the problem. As I'm experiencing something different. Please take a look at the blend file.

Comment: I saw that one and it didn't help me.

Comment: Pherion, it doesn't really matter one way or the other, it's just site "book-keeping"  There is no way to know if you had checked that one out or not, by title they do appear duplicates.

Comment: Any specific reason why this hand is 27.5 meters long? Such a high scale messes with the physics emission parameters as well as the child interpolation.

Comment: Because this was a sculpted mesh and I didn't rescale. And from experience, scaling it down to real sizes also causes many problems.